# COUNTIF header row cell Length is less than a value and range might contain #N/A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, countif

In `Column A` I want to count all the cells in range `B2:J2` that their header row cell LEN is less than 17, but one of the cells in my range `B2:J2` might be `#N/A`.

In the example I shared only the cells that are highlighted in grey are relevant, and the formula should return 2.

I would love to get your help.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(B1:J1)<17)*NOT(ISERROR(B2:J2))*NOT(ISBLANK(B2:J2)))
```

[image]